# How do you pull XHTML out of an ATOM feed using Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, atom-feed

I am trying to pull some XHTML out of an RSS feed so I can place it in a WebView. The RSS feed in question has a tag called `<content>` and the characters inside the content are XHTML. (The site I'm paring is a blogger feed) 
What is the best way to try to pull this content? The `<` characters are confusing my parser. I have tried both DOM and SAX but neither can handle this very well.

[Here is a sample of the XML as requested.](http://pastebin.com/pbUB7DQF) In this case, I want basically XHTML inside the content tag to be a string. `<content> XHTML </content>`

Edit: based on ignyhere's suggestion I have tried XPath, but I am still having the same issue. [Here is a pastebin sample of my tests.](http://pastebin.com/UFhtyg87)

Comment: can you include some sample xhtml ?

Comment: @Waqas I have updated my question with a sample.

Comment: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/02/22/rome-parse-publish-rss-atom-feeds-java.html or another lib http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=3308

Comment: @ant it doesn't seem that either of the libraries are compatible with Android, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this is (the essence of) what I use to parse an ATOM feed from Blogger using [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).  The code is pretty icky, but it is from a real app.  You can probably get the general flavor of it, anyway.

```
    final String TAG_FEED = "feed";

public int parseXml(Reader reader) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    int entries = 0;

    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(reader);

        while (true) {
            int eventType = xpp.next();
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                break;
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                out.append("Start document\n");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                String tag = xpp.getName();
                // out.append("Start tag " + tag + "\n");
                if (TAG_FEED.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    entries = parseFeed(xpp);
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                // out.append("End tag " + xpp.getName() + "\n");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                // out.append("Text " + xpp.getText() + "\n");
            }
        }
        out.append("End document\n");

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //        return out.toString();
    return entries;

}

private int parseFeed(XmlPullParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int depth = xpp.getDepth();
    assert (depth == 1);
    int eventType;
    int entries = 0;
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, TAG_FEED);
    while (((eventType = xpp.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) && (xpp.getDepth() > depth)) {
        // loop invariant: At this point, the parser is not sitting on
        // end-of-document, and is at a level deeper than where it started.

        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            String tag = xpp.getName();
            // Log.d("parseFeed", "Start tag: " + tag);    // Uncomment to debug
            if (FeedEntry.TAG_ENTRY.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                FeedEntry feedEntry = new FeedEntry(xpp);
                feedEntry.persist(this);
                entries++;
                // Log.d("FeedEntry", feedEntry.title);    // Uncomment to debug
                // xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, tag);
            }
        }
    }
    assert (depth == 1);
    return entries;
}

class FeedEntry {
    String id;
    String published;
    String updated;
    // Timestamp lastRead;
    String title;
    String subtitle;
    String authorName;
    int contentType;
    String content;
    String preview;
    String origLink;
    String thumbnailUri;
    // Media media;

    static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry";
    static final String TAG_ENTRY_ID = "id";
    static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    static final String TAG_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    static final String TAG_UPDATED = "updated";
    static final String TAG_PUBLISHED = "published";
    static final String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";
    static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";
    static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    static final String TAG_ORIG_LINK = "origLink";
    static final String TAG_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
    static final String ATTRIBUTE_URL = "url";

    /**
    * Create a FeedEntry by pulling its bits out of an XML Pull Parser. Side effect: Advances
    * XmlPullParser.
    * 
    * @param xpp
    */
public FeedEntry(XmlPullParser xpp) {
    int eventType;
    int depth = xpp.getDepth();
    assert (depth == 2);
    try {
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, TAG_ENTRY);
        while (((eventType = xpp.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        && (xpp.getDepth() > depth)) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                String tag = xpp.getName();
                if (TAG_ENTRY_ID.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    id = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_ENTRY_ID);
                } else if (TAG_TITLE.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    title = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_TITLE);
                } else if (TAG_SUBTITLE.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    subtitle = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_SUBTITLE);
                } else if (TAG_UPDATED.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    updated = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_UPDATED);
                } else if (TAG_PUBLISHED.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    published = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_PUBLISHED);
                } else if (TAG_CONTENT.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                    int attributeCount = xpp.getAttributeCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < attributeCount; i++) {
                        String attributeName = xpp.getAttributeName(i);
                        if (attributeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_TYPE)) {
                            String attributeValue = xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
                            if (attributeValue
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HTML)) {
                                contentType = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.CONTENT_TYPE_HTML;
                                } else if (attributeValue
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_XHTML)) {
                                    contentType = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.CONTENT_TYPE_XHTML;
                                } else {
                                    contentType = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        content = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_CONTENT);
                        extractPreview();
                    } else if (TAG_AUTHOR.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                        // Skip author for now -- it is complicated
                        int authorDepth = xpp.getDepth();
                        assert (authorDepth == 3);
                        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, TAG_AUTHOR);
                        while (((eventType = xpp.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                        && (xpp.getDepth() > authorDepth)) {
                        }
                        assert (xpp.getDepth() == 3);
                        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, TAG_AUTHOR);

                    } else if (TAG_ORIG_LINK.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                        origLink = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, TAG_ORIG_LINK);
                    } else if (TAG_THUMBNAIL.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                        thumbnailUri = Util.XmlPullAttribute(xpp, tag, null, ATTRIBUTE_URL);
                    } else {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                            String throwAway = Util.XmlPullTag(xpp, tag);
                    }
                }
            } // while
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert (xpp.getDepth() == 2);
    }
}

public static String XmlPullTag(XmlPullParser xpp, String tag) 
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, tag);
    String itemText = xpp.nextText();
    if (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        xpp.nextTag();
    }
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, tag);
    return itemText;
}

public static String XmlPullAttribute(XmlPullParser xpp, 
    String tag, String namespace, String name)
throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    assert (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tag));
    assert (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name));
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, tag);
    String itemText = xpp.getAttributeValue(namespace, name);
    if (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        xpp.nextTag();
    }
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, tag);
    return itemText;
}
```

I'll give you a hint: None of the return values matter.  The data is saved into a database by a method (not shown) called at this line:

```
feedEntry.persist(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! A lot to soak in here, this looks like a much better and more robust solution than what I ended up using so I can't wait to try to work this in once I get some downtime.

Answer (score 3):

I would attempt to attack it with XPath. Would something like this work?

```
public static String parseAtom (InputStream atomIS) 
   throws Exception { 

   // Below should yield the second content block
   String xpathString = "(//*[starts-with(name(),"content")])[2]";
   // or, String xpathString = "//*[name() = 'content'][2]";
   // remove the '[2]' to get all content tags or get the count, 
   // if needed, and then target specific blocks 
   //String xpathString = "count(//*[starts-with(name(),"content")])"; 
   // note the evaluate expression below returns a glob and not a node set

   XPathFactory xpf              = XPathFactory.newInstance (); 
   XPath xpath                   = xpf.newXPath (); 
   XPathExpression xpathCompiled = xpath.compile (xpathString); 

   // use the first to recast and evaluate as NodeList 
   //Object atomOut = xpathCompiled.evaluate ( 
   //   new InputSource (atomIS), XPathConstants.NODESET); 
   String atomOut = xpathCompiled.evaluate ( 
      new InputSource (atomIS), XPathConstants.STRING); 

   System.out.println (atomOut); 

   return atomOut; 

}
```

Comment: Not quite working, I don't suppose you can give a more robust sample? I am not very familiar with Xpath so perhaps I'm making a silly mistake. I'll update my question with a pastebin of my test if you care to look.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the XPath expression to work in the given scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the update, when I have some downtime I'll have to test with your xpath. However I was able to get a handle on the content node I was after (the issue was namespace) but it still wasn't pulling out the xhtml in full.  Still upvotes for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I can see your problem here, the reason why these parsers are not producing the correct result is because contents of your `<content>` tag are not wrapped into `<![CDATA[ ]]>`, what I would do until I find more adequate solution I'd use quick and dirty trick :

```
private void parseFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean match = false;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("<content")){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                match = true;
                continue;
            }

            if(match){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                match = false;
            }

            if(line.contains("</content")){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

This will give you all content in String. You can optionaly seperate them by slightly modyfiying this method or if you don't need actual `<content>` you can filter that out as well.

Comment: Thanks for your insight about CDATA, I ended up just doing a string replace to add the CDATA tag after the content. SAX still couldn't handle it but DOM is reading it as I wanted. Probably not the best solution but it meets my requirement.

Comment: Untrue. There is no requirement in xml that element content need be wrapped in CDATA. This is only necessary when the data is not properly encoded for XML. He is working with what the server provides and it should not be mandatory to change the result set.

Comment: @ingyhere yeah I'm not saying I'm happy with the solution, I'm just saying at least it works :-)

Comment: I'm not happy with the answer as well hence the `quick and dirty`. Those never last and should be avoided at all costs